# Calculating the Duration of No Data in gcp monitoring for greater than one day

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, google-cloud-monitoring

Hello currently  I am getting data that pulls monitoring data from a custom metric for the last 30 minutes:

```
def list_time_series(project_id):
    # [START monitoring_read_timeseries_simple]
    client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
    project_name = f"projects/{project_id}"
    interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval()

    now = time.time()
    seconds = int(now)
    nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
    interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
        {
            "end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos},
            "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 1800), "nanos": nanos},
        }
    )

    results = client.list_time_series(
        request={
            "name": project_name,
            "filter": "metric.type=\"custom.googleapis.com/tester/test\" resource.type=\"dataflow_job\" resource.label.\"job_name\"=monitoring.regex.full_match(\"character_(TOM|DICK|HARRY)\")",
            "interval": interval,
            "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
        }
    )
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

The issue I am currently  encountering  is that certain days the job name may have periods of no data coming in that is more than a day. Cloud monitoring alerting condition for data is a day , so I cannot use it in this case. How can I calculate the duration of no data for these job names ?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data

Comment: @itprorh66 ok i will send screenshots give me one sec

Comment: Please don't send screen shots, provide data that can copied and pasted for use in diagnosing the issue